# DataCacheClients error, what might be the cause?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, moq, rhino-mocks

My team is using Moq as the testing framework. Since we need to test some http objects, sessions in particular, we explored some more options, and found a nice library called [MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/), which downloaded RhinoMocks while installing. When trying to call a method from MVCContrib, I get this error:

> Test method
>   uBetPro.UI.Web.Tests.AccountController.AccountControllerTests.
>   .Login_CorrectCredentials_AuthenticationSuccess_ReturnsValidLicense
>   threw exception:  System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException:
>   Configuration system  failed to initialize ---> 
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized
>   configuration section
>   dataCacheClients.
>   (C:\Users\Shogun\AppData\Local\Temp\TestResults\Shogun 2013-06-27
>   15_23_17\Out\uBetPro.UI.Web.Tests.DLL.config line 27)

What might be causing this? I'd be glad if there's a way I can fix this, but my common sense implies that two different testing frameworks can't function in the same project, does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have an issue in your uBetPro.UI.Web.Tests.DLL.config at line 27

I would assume that you've got something you haven't mocked out correctly and it's trying to read from the config file

If it was a collision between mocking frameworks I would have expected to see compile time errors before you got as far as running tests